# Visual studio cross linking DLL built from different VC compiler

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, dll, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Is linking a project with a library that is built with different version of  tool set compatible. When I tried this between VS2015/2013, the C++ linker complained MSVC_version are different.

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1900' doesn't match value '1800'
```

- Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?
- If this is expected, since compilers generate the platform specific code, why is this not allowed?An example contrary I came up with is, if C++11 changed int definition to be 64 bit wide vs C++03 complaint old compiler just 32 bits.But it still seems that with smart compiler/linker options this can be allowed?

Finally, I stumbled on this while I am trying to use a open source library that uses C++11 features quite a bit. But a lot of my projects existing code is in 2013. Is there anyway to use the library features with out complete upgrade of my project? I am sure I am missing something as a lot of libs should work independently like api libraries using old drivers install in old windows machines etc., What am I missing?

-Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'universal ABI' for C/C++, but you can generally get C-style exports on Intel platforms to link against other C-style exports on Intel platforms as long as you make sure they are using a consistent calling convention. If they are using the same name-mangling scheme, you can get some C++ code to link with other C++ code from a different compiler--Intel goes through some effort to make their complier link-compatible with Visual C++.

This of course all falls down with inline code, and in particular the Standard C++ Library is not guaranteed to match up. The link error is there because Visual C++ only maintains Compiler/Standard Library compatibility in the same version (i.e. Update 1 to Update 2), but not between major versions (VS 2013 to VS 2015).

> Note that with VS 2017, the C/C++ Library is actually the same as the VS 2015 version.

Comment: Thank you. ABI is the magic word I was looking for. Quite a read on  how OS'es actually design and use the drivers. This directly answers second part of the question. In case of C compiler with same name mangling and C version, is it always safe to cross link? I am wondering if it can cause unknown memory/pointer issues during run-time as there is no standard ABI

Comment: It's safe if they are using the same name mangling and the same calling convention. For Windows x86 code that's ``cdecl``, ``stdcall``, ``fastcall``, or ``vectorcall``.

Comment: It's not necessarily safe. For example, the internal format of `va_list` or `jmp_buf` can change between compiler versions.

Comment: Fair enough: safe-ish :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many subtle things which can change between compiler versions that can render them incompatible.

- The order of base classes.
- The order of member variables with different access specifiers.
- Structure padding.
- The implementation of standard library classes such as `std::vector`.
- Internal implementation helper functions for non-inlined primitives such as shifting a 64-bit integer left on a 32-bit system.
- Internal implementation helper functions for features such as RTTI, [stack probes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6f1y6x3.aspx), [GS](http://blogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2012/01/26/enhancements-to-gs-in-visual-studio-11/), [CFG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919635.aspx).
- The internal format of [LTCG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx) object files.

Any of these would result in object files compiled by one version of the compiler not being compatible with object files compiled by a different version of the compiler. Some of these incompatibilities would result in link errors, but others would result in an executable which exhibited mysterious runtime errors.